# how to modify javascript code for subtraction

Tags: javascript

This code was doing function sum. I want to make this work like subtraction

```js
function finddeductions() {
  var arr = document.getElementsByClassName("deductions");
  var tot = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseInt(arr[i].value))
      tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById('totaldeductions').value = tot;
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML and expected input/output

Comment: Replace plus with minus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tot -= parseInt(arr[i].value);
```